# Why do I only have 2 paragon with 121 kittens in year 3172?

Tags: kittens-game

Okay, so I have 121 kittens, I'm in in year 3172, but have only 2 paragon. I just unlocked metaphysics, and when i went to the [wiki page for paragon](http://bloodrizer.ru/games/kittens/wiki/index.php?page=paragon). It tells me each kitten over 70 provides one paragon, and that I should get one for every 1000 years of gameplay. So, I should have 54 paragon, right?

The only thing I can think of is that I haven't reset yet, so I would have to reset for those rules to kick in. However, I want to be sure of that before I do my first reset.

Does anyone know why I only have 2 paragon?

Answer (score 4):

The paragon for your kittens total is only awarded when you reset.  So if you reset now, you will receive 51 paragon along with your start from kitten zero, on top of the 2 you have now.  (You'd have to re-research Metaphysics at that point; although the upgrades you can get with it stay, the tech itself won't stay unlocked for you)

That said, by your math, you should have 3 paragon right now, and I don't quite understand why.  Possibly that is not awarded on the fly, and will update when the webpage updates (save and refresh might do it).

Comment: thank you so much for responding! 

so I have to reset to get the 51 paragon? or do I have to reset and wait until I've researched metaphysics again to recieve the 51 paragon?

I do have 3 paragon now, btw! I think you were right about the save and refresh.

please forgive me if I ask for clarifications on things it feels like you've answered - I tend to take things very literally and have a lot of trouble understanding unless whatever's being said is made very explicit.

Comment: @eyjayy - you receive the 51 paragon immediately after reset, and it immediately provides the bonuses to production and storage that are described on that page you linked.  The Metaphysics technology, when you eventually get unobtanium to research it, simply opens up the area where that paragon can be spent on other permanent upgrades.